# Relation between rpc client (proxy) username and node Identity

Tags: corda

In Corda we are using CordaRPCClient to initiate transaction from the client. Here we are passing username and password to start the connection. Right now I am using hardcoded user name and password. Can I map this to a user table which is there in DB. Please share if there any best practices exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can definitely have rpc users fetched from a database. All you would need is some configuration in the nodes configuration file (node.conf).

The users are generally defined in the security block. Below is how it can be configured.

```
security = {
  authService = {
    dataSource = {
        type = "DB"
        passwordEncryption = "SHIRO_1_CRYPT"
        connection = {
           jdbcUrl = "<jdbc connection string>"
           username = "<db username>"
           password = "<db user password>"
           driverClassName = "<JDBC driver>"
        }
    }
    options = {
         cache = {
            expireAfterSecs = 120
            maxEntries = 10000
         }
    }
}
```

You could find more details in our documentation [here](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.8/open-source/clientrpc.html#managing-rpc-security).